# WFFM: Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: wffm

I have Web Forms for Marketers 8.2 rev. 160801. On my local machine.
I've created simple form and assigned an action 'Send Email Message' on submit.
Form can be successfully submitted, but **no emails sent**.

My parameters for 'Send Email Message' are:

```
<Host>smtp.mingo.local</Host><port>25</port><From>noreply@mingo.com</From><IsBodyHtml>true</IsBodyHtml>
```

Web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="noreply@mingo.com">
        <network host="smtp.mingo.local" port="25" defaultCredentials="false"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true"/>
    <settings>
    </settings>
  </system.net>
```

smtp.mingo.local on port 25 is working. I've checked with Telnet. It responds.

But I have following in logs:

> ManagedPoolThread #17 2016:12:06 11:03:49 ERROR Exception in task
>   Exception: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException Message: Failure sending
>   mail. Source: System    at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage
>   message)    at Sitecore.Tasks.EmailReminderTask.SendReminder(Item
>   item)    at Sitecore.Tasks.EmailReminderTask.SendReminder()    at
>   Sitecore.Tasks.TaskDatabaseAgent.Run()
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.Net.WebException Message: Unable to connect to the
>   remote server Source: System    at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream,
>   Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket,
>   Socket& abortSocket6)    at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object
>   owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)    at
>   System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject,
>   GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)    at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint
>   servicePoint)    at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage
>   message)
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException Message: An attempt was
>   made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
>   xx.xx.xx.xx:25 Source: System    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress)    at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
>   exception)

Does anybody knows what can be an issue?

What did I miss?

Comment: I dont think that error is related to your WFFM email action, as its coming from scheduled task 'Sitecore.Tasks.EmailReminderTask.SendReminder', Can you check whats in the logs at the exact time you submit the form?

Comment: you can try using smtp4dev tool in your local instance and see if emails get sent correctly. you have to set the host parameter value to 'localhost' when you are using this tool.

Comment: Except error above, I have 'ERROR Must have Sitecore.MSCRM license to use Microsoft Dynamics CRM security provider', 'ERROR Failed to perform GeoIp lookup for...' and 'Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Layouts/Renderings/Common/PageCodes/PageCode.cshtml'

Comment: I tried SMTP tool and I was able to send email (but email body was empty)

Comment: Does the values for the tags MailServer, MailServerUserName, etc show on the showconfig page?
Also have you made sure there isn't anything on IIS preventing you from connecting to this smtp server?

Comment: Is this an actual smtp server? If it is you might want to check if the email recipient of the send email WFFM save action is set correctly

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there has been no followup, and the original post is likely related to misconfiguration rather than a systemic error that would benefit others.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set these configurations directly on the web.config?

you should be using the host and authentication tags on the Sitecore.config file like this:

```
<Host>smtp-mail.outlook.com</Host><Port>587</Port><EnableSsl>true</EnableSsl><Login>sitecore@outlook.com</Login><Password>xyz1234<Password><IsBodyHtml>true</IsBodyHtml>
```

you can check how to configure smtp for WFFM [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/web_forms_for_marketers/working_with_actions_and_validations/save_actions/specify_different_smtp_settings_for_the_send_email_message_save_action)

Comment: i think this steps is only necessary if we are using multi-server setup with email sending configured in CD instance

Comment: Yes, I have these configurations on Web.config.

I've added in Sitecore.config:

<setting name="MailServer" value="smtp.mingo.local" />
<setting name="MailServerUserName" value="" />
<setting name="MailServerPassword" value="" />
<setting name="MailServerPort" value="25" />

and at sitecore/System/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Actions/Save Actions > Send Email Message:

<Host>smtp.mingo.local</Host><port>25</port><From>noreply@mingo.com</From><IsBodyHtml>true</IsBodyHtml>

but it still not working

Comment: yeah I forgot to mention that this was for scaled environments